# Activating AND nodes and OR nodes

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, workflow, graph-algorithm, computation-theory

Consider a directed graph with AND nodes and OR nodes. The AND nodes are activated only when all the in edges into it are activated. The OR nodes are activated if at least one of the in edges into it is activated. How to design an **efficient algorithm** to decide if all nodes can be activated? I have thought of some naive algorithm but it takes O(n^3) time. I am also assuming that vertices with no in edges into them are activated initially.I believe n^3 cannot be an efficient algorithm and there's some method that I am missing. Tagging domains where the problem might have a solution.

Comment: All nodes with no incoming edges are activated initially and then you propagate that through the graph and want to know if all nodes have become activated?

Comment: Yes, an algorithm that isn't too naive..

Comment: This is not a digital logic circuit. It is a graph. I am sorry if the question was confusing. I haven't mentioned any tags related to digital logic circuit.

Comment: Peter's answer is better -- I think you should accept that rather than mine.

Comment: I must be missing something, because it seems that the answer will always be "YES" -- since how could even one node possibly not be activated?

Comment: What if there is a pair of AND nodes with edges to each other @j_random_hacker

Comment: In that case, setting all of their inputs and all of their outputs to "activated" creates no contradiction, so it seems to me like the answer is still "YES".  More generally: set every node to "activated", and observe that there are no contradictions (that is, active OR nodes that have 0 active inputs, inactive OR nodes that have > 0 active inputs, active AND nodes that have < 2 active inputs, or inactive AND nodes that have 2 active inputs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could preprocess the graph to compute the in-degree of each node.

Add all nodes with in-degree 0 to a stack, and prepare an array A containing the activation count for each node (initially equal to 0).

Then do the following pseudo-code

```
visited = set(stack)
while stack:
   node = stack.pop()
   for dest in node.neighbours():
      A[dest] += 1
      if ((Type[dest]==AND and A[dest]==indegree[dest]) or
          (Type[dest]==OR and A[dest]>0)):
         if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            stack.append(dest)
```

This will visit each edge and each node at most once, so will have linear complexity.

When you finish the process, visited contains the set of activated nodes.

Comment: I think this is essentially the same as my code, only more elegant :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words: I guess it is a question of perspective - your solution looked better to me :)

Answer (score 4):

Maintain a set `A` of already activated nodes, a queue `Q` of nodes, and counters `C` of in-edges for each node.

Start by counting in-edges:

```
for each n in nodes {
    for each n2 adjacent to n {
        C[n2] += 1
    }
}
```

Then initialize Q with the nodes with no in-edges:

```
for each n in nodes {
    if C[n] == 0 {
        add n to Q
    }
}
```

Now repeat this process, until the queue is empty:

```
take q from Q
for each n adjacent to q {
   if n is in A { continue }
   if n is OR {
      add n to A
      add n to Q
   } else { // n must be AND
      C[n] -= 1
      if C[n] is 0 {
          add n to A
          add n to Q
      }
   }
}
```

[This is a variant of topological sort that copes with the differences between OR and AND nodes].

When this process terminates, the set `A` contains all activated nodes.

The runtime is O(V+E), where V is the number of nodes in the graph, and E the number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in O(n). Here is a possible algorithm.

`n` the total number of nodes

`s` the sum of the nodes that have been activated

`a` array to indicate if node n has been activated

`c` array to count the number of incoming edges for node n

Iterate through the nodes, if they have no incoming edges call your propagation function with it, e.g. `propagate(i);`.

If `s == n` all nodes have been activated.

Pseudo code for the `propagate` function:

```
function propagate(idx) {
    if (a[idx]) // is node activated already
        return; // return because node was already propagated
    a[idx] = true; // activate
    s++; // increase the number of activated nodes
    for (var j = 0; j < outEdges[idx].length; j++) { // iterate through the outgoing edges
        var idx2 = outEdges[idx][j]; // the node the edge is pointing to
        if (isOrNode[idx2]) {
            propagate(idx2);
        } else { // AND node
            c[idx2]++; // increase the count of incoming activated edges
            if (inEdges[idx2].length == c[idx2]) // all incoming edges have been activated
                propagate(idx2);
        }
    }
}
```